# Angularjs: Reload on path change but not search parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
$stateProvider.state('search-results', {
        url: '/s/:path?param1&param2&param3',
        controller: '...Controller',
        templateUrl: '....html',
        reloadOnSearch:false
      });
```

Now I want the controller not to load when there is change in the param1, param2 or param3. But I want controller to load when there is change in the path.

When I do

```
$state.go('search-results', {
  path: "path",
  param1: "param1",
  param2: "param2",
  param3: "param3"
})
```

With a new path, the controller doesn't reload. Infact the URL also deosn't change. I can get around the URL problem by using $location. But in that case also the controller is not reloaded.

Note: I found some similar questions, but since I am using $state instead of $route, my question is different.